# Why can't I connect to my socket.io server in WebView Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, socket.io

i have an html file and i run it in a webview in android studio but it does not connect with socket.io there is no problem with the html file because the same file connects on the computer.

this is my html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Leaflet Popup Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./leaflet/leaflet.css"/>
        <script src="./leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="./socket_io.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapid" style="height: 100vh;"></div>
        <script>
            var socket = io("http://xxxxx:3000");

            var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([39.9042, 32.6227], 5);

            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
            }).addTo(mymap);
            var placedMarkers = [];
            socket.on("clientLocations", (data) => {
                placedMarkers.forEach(function(placedMarkers) {
                    mymap.removeLayer(placedMarkers);
                });
                placedMarkers = [];
                markers = data;
                var bounds = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var marker = L.marker(markers[i].location).addTo(mymap);
                    placedMarkers.push(marker);

                    var popup = L.popup({
                    autoClose: false,
                    closeOnClick: false,
                    closeButton: false,
                    }).setContent(markers[i].name);

                    marker.bindPopup(popup).openPopup();
                    bounds.push(markers[i].location);
                }

                mymap.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: [100, 100], maxZoom: 100 });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my kotlin code:

```kotlin
val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html")
```

and i have these permissions:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Allow clear text traffic in application tag of manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to the application tag in the **`AndroidManifest.xml`** file and the problem was solved.

Thanks to Blackapps for the comment and for giving me the solution.